# Ubuntu problem on HP laptop

Tags: error-handling

I have an HP notebook with the following specifications:

|  | Detail |
| --- | --- |
| Model | 15da0xx |
| CPU | 8th Generation Intel Core i7 |
| RAM | 8GB |
| Video | Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (256MB) |
| Storage | 500GB SSD |

I've been using Ubuntu LTS 20.04 for a month and I've had a number of issues that did not exist on Windows 10.

1. sometimes the computer just freeze randomly (can happen at anytime maybe when i use google chrome or read a pdf file or using office,cant do anything, just removed the power)

This is the result of free -m

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7865        3012        1193         404        3659        4174
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

2. the sound from the speaker crackles
3. sometimes I cannot control the mouse, it automatically clicks anything on the screen over the place (just like freezing error)
4. the sound from the headphone jack crackles
5. Wifi is unstable and disconnect randomly
   result of sudo lshw -C network

```
      description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 10:62:e5:e2:70:42
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-35-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 74:40:bb:71:20:d9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.13.0-35-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

result of sudo lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

6. Cant connect the bluetooth
7. It doesn't regconize usb boot (doesnt show usb boot on booting device menu) when im trying to go back to win10 (my usb boot is fine)

How can I track down the source of these problems and fix them? Alternatively, how can I install Debian? I tried to install that operating system, but had an error.

I want to stick with Linux to improve my skills for later.

Comment: This question is far too broad, touching on many different issues. It would be better to split this into four questions: (1) Wifi/Bluetooth (2) sound (3) freezing (4) mouse control. When asking about WiFi/Bluetooth, be sure to include the Terminal output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo lspci`, as this will show specific information about your network card and setup. For the freezing, be sure to explain what you're doing when the system freezes, and also include the Terminal output of `free -m` to show your memory configuration. By going through these one at a time, you may receive answers.

Comment: Can you spend little time help me find problem and fix it one by one. I'm quite new at ubuntu and really confuse, thank you a lot.

Comment: I'll be really graceful. I really want to stay with linux.

Comment: you need to post the output of the terminal commands,just copy and paste the commands into terminal one by one,then edit your question and copy paste the output into your question.

Comment: i did the command, please check it for me

Comment: For the WiFi/BT only: Open Additional Drivers, select and apply the recommended Realtek proprietary driver. Reboot.